# Can I force \captionsetup to position caption above the table?

Tags: tables, captions

My institution's thesis writing requires table captions to be located on the top of all tables. Although that is declared in the .cls file of the template provided by university within the first chunck of the code bellow,
in the final output all table captions are placed at the bottom of table. How can I force table captions to appear above.

Lines controlling the position of the captions (from the  .cls file):

```
        \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{fbe2015}{\bf\space:\space}
        \captionsetup[table]{labelsep=fbe2015, position=above, justification=centering ,aboveskip=0.3truecm, belowskip=6pt}
```

A code part I used in the main body of the thesis that positions captions at the bottom, despite previous commands in the .cls file:

```
 \begin{document}      
            \begin{table}[]
        \caption{Significance of models indicators.}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{lcclc}
            \hline
            &  R-square & F-Test Stat & AIC & SSE \\
            \hline \hline
        Alpha Powder    &   0.85    &   49.80   &   843 &   0.30 \\
        Alpha Liquid    &   0.87    &   78.50   &   529 &   0.28 \\
        \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \label{tab:my_label}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is something keeping you from placing the `\caption` directives before rather than after the associated `tabular` environments?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragments into a compilable document that people can play with. The position of the caption within a `{table}` environment is determined by whether the `\caption` command is issued before the `{tabular}` or after the `{tabular}`. The `caption` package `position` key is only used to determine the correct spacing around the captions. So if your captions precede the `{tabular}` use `position=above`. The class is using that setting because it assumes you will place the `\caption` *before* the `{tabular}`.

Comment: Still a fragment... But if I paste this into a document containing `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{caption}` the caption is above the table. So maybe your class is doing something, in which case you need to link to the class itself.

Comment: As I understand the thesis template defines its own documentclass embeded on .cls file 
`\documentclass[onluarkali,ingilizce,doktora,bez,LisansustuEgitim]{itutez}` . This captionsetup part is located at the .cls file.

Comment: The typographic tradition places table captions *above* the table.

Comment: That still doesn't give us any information that we can use.  If you're wanting a fast answer, dig through the class file and figure out what part is causing the caption to appear below the table, so that you can create a MWE.  If you don't need a fast answer, you can post a link to the class file and see how long it takes.

Comment: @Teepeemn thank you very much for your comment. Here I am sharing link to cls file. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12VAiWORpIBYqNN0JXc-K_FzYHtkOoKrY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't read the file of your link...

Comment: Did you get the class file from here? https://github.com/alperenkaran/itu-thesis-template If so, the captions on the sample document are properly placed above the table, so I don't think the problem is with the class.